Prove that any preadditive category can be embedded into an additive category as a full subcategory
I am trying to prove that any preadditive category $\mathcal{C}$ can be embedded as a full subcategory into an additive category $\mathcal{D}$.
Since an additive category is, by definition, a preadditive category admitting all finitary biproducts, and since $\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary preadditive category, it makes sense to try to construct such a category $\mathcal{D}$. What I am thinking of is so far the following: Let $A_1,\dots,A_k$ be objects in $\mathcal{C}$. If they do not have a product or a coproduct, then I can simply introduce a biproduct $B_{A_1,\dots, A_k}$ as a new object in $\mathcal{D}$ and introduce also $p_j, e_k$ projections and inclusions, and also introduce to $\mathcal{D}$ the rules of composition so that they will satisfy the requirement for $B_{A_1,\dots,A_k}$ to be the biproduct $A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_k$ of $A_1,\dots,A_k$. However, I am having difficulty in the case when $A_1,\dots,A_k$ already have a product or a coproduct but does not have a product. Suppose that there exists the coproduct $A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_k$ for the $k$ objects. Then we cannot simply introduce the projections $p_k : \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i} A_i \to A_k$ as a new morphism in $\mathcal{D}$, since we want $\mathcal{C}$ to be a full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$.
Do you see a way out of this dilemma? If there is another approach to solve this problem, I would be grateful for your input.

In a preadditive category, any finite product or coproduct is already a biproduct. For example, suppose $A\times B$ is a product of $A$ and $B$, so it comes with projection maps $A\times B\to A$ and $A\times B\to B$. By the universal property of a product, if $C$ is any object, then a pair of maps $C\to A$ and $C\to B$ induces a map $C\to A\times B$. Applying this to $\operatorname{id}_A:A\to A$ and $0:A\to B$ gives a map $A\to A\times B$, and similarly we get a map $B\to A\times B$, and it's not hard to check that these maps have the properties of the inclusion maps in the definition of a biproduct.
By the way, if you want to construct an additive category by adjoining biproducts, then you don't need to worry about whether the biproducts already exist. If you adjoin a biproduct in the way that you describe, then it will automatically be isomorphic to any biproduct that already exists.
There's a slicker way to do this. By Yoneda's Lemma, $\mathcal{C}$ embeds as a full subcategory of the category of additive fuunctors $\mathcal{C}^{op}\to\mathcal{Ab}$ by $A\mapsto\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,A)$. This functor category is not only additive, but abelian, although it may not be locally small. But by taking the full subcategory consisting of functors that are summands of finite biproducts of functors of the form $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,A)$ you will get a locally small additive category into which $\mathcal{C}$ fully embeds.
